# How do I use `.hover()`when the element is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a HTML page, and now I've made the content with HTML and CSS, I'd like to add behaviour with Javascript and jQuery. I have a band on the top of my page made in CSS (with id `#band`). I want it to:

- Put buttons on it which let the user change background color (done)
- Show onload (done)
- After loading, `fadeOut(500)` (done)
- onhover, show
- when not, hovering hide

However, the script in the `.hover(function(){})` is not running. Why is this? To let you reproduce my problem, here is the code below:

I have done a few tests and:

- The syntax is correct
- The jQuery works (in particular `fadeIn()`)

I believe the problem is that the `<div id="band">`is unloading when it fades out, meaning there is nothing to detect. How do I overcome this?

```js
function A() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF1493";
}

function B() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#22F822";
}

function C() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#888888";
}

function D() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#2262FF";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#band").fadeOut(750);
  $("#band").hover($("#band").fadeIn(750),$("#band").fadeOut(750));
});
```

```css
/*Basic Format*/

#band {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #959595;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#colors {
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.buttoncolor {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#buttonA {
  background-color: #FF1493;
}

#buttonB {
  background-color: #22F822;
}

#buttonC {
  background-color: #888888;
}

#buttonD {
  background-color: #2262FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="A()">

  <div class="fade" id="band">
    <div id="colors">
      <button type="button" class="buttoncolor" id="buttonA" onclick="A()"></button>
      <button type="button" class="buttoncolor" id="buttonB" onclick="B()"></button>
      <button type="button" class="buttoncolor" id="buttonC" onclick="C()"></button>
      <button type="button" class="buttoncolor" id="buttonD" onclick="D()"></button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div><h1>TITLE</h1></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your snippet has a syntax error: `$("$this")`, and also the `hover()` logic itself is incorrect.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok, however, isn't `.hover()`syntax `$(element).hover(function(if true),function(if false))`?

Comment: Yes, but you're executing the `fadeIn()` immediately and assigning its result to the event handler, and you have no function defined as `fadeOut()`. You need to wrap them in anonymous functions. However, to save you some time, hidden elements do not trigger `mouseenter` events (which is what `hover()` listens for) so this pattern is flawed from the start. I'd suggest you wither leave the bar shrunk in height or width to allow there to be at least something to hover over, instead of hiding it completely, or instead toggle it by button click.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`are jQuery statements.

Comment: I'm aware, but you need to 1) call `fadeOut()` on an element. At the moment you're just calling a function called `fadeOut()` which seemingly doesn't exist. 2) Wrap those function calls themselves in anonymous functions, as you need to provide a *function reference* to the event handler, not the *result of a function handler assignment*

Comment: If you're confused about that I'd suggest looking at the jQuery docs as they have lots of examples you can reference: http://api.jquery.com/hover/. However as I stated, this isn't going to work in the manner you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok. So I should use a `.css("height", 1)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170796/discussion-between-vortexyt-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: You could, but that's an awfully small margin. You'd be expecting your users to find a 1px element and hover it. I'd suggest 25px at least, with some kind of icon to make it obvious what the function will be when you hover.

Comment: Or maybe set `z-index` to 2?

Comment: You could, but that doesn't improve the tiny hit area

Comment: So I won't change the height, but change the z-index

Comment: That alone won't work. As I've said before, hidden elements do not raise `mouseenter` events.

Comment: So a button that brings up `#band` which allows to change the background color?

Comment: Yep, that could work.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, I appreciate your time.

Comment: @VortexYT a better solution is to have a parent element wrapping the `#band` element which has a height and width same as `#band` but transparent background. So you can write a `hover` event on this parent element and when it does you can simply show the `#band`.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy ok thanks. I might try that next.